# Browser Auto Scrolling for tabbing through form elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

When tabbing to a form field that is below the bottom of the viewport (or typing in a textarea that overlaps the bottom), browsers usually automatically scroll up enough so that you can see the field. Is there a way to set the position the browser moves to?

This is an issue because I have a fixed position bar at the bottom of the page and so it covers up where the browser scrolls to and would like it to scroll up further.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could add a focus event handler to your inputs and check their position onfocus.  If it's too close to the bottom, just bump the window scroll a bit until it's acceptable.

Below is how you could do it in jQuery:

```
// Constant amount of padding an element should be from the bottom of the window
var padding = 50;

// Add focus event to all your different form elements
$("input, textarea, select").focus(function(){

    // Check their position relative to the window's scroll
    var elementBottom = $(this).offset().top + $(this).height();
    var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowBottom = windowScroll + $(window).height();

    if(elementBottom + padding > windowBottom){
        $(window).scrollTop(windowScroll + padding);
    }

});
```

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/XJLWU/).

**Edit: Typing in textarea**

You could capture and check the position of the textarea during typing using the [keydown event](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/) handler:

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(){
    // same logic as above to check textarea position relative to window
});
```

Comment: Hi Pat, thanks for the response, I did end up doing this. However there's also the fact that when typing in a textarea that overlaps the bottom of the viewport the window scrolls to the cursor so that it doesn't disappear. Would this be possible to change too?

Comment: Not a problem and sure it would be possible - see my edits for how you could do it.